# Tomahawk and scrolling tabs

Tags: java, jsf, tomahawk

is there a tomahawk component, that enables "scrollable tabs"? What I mean is something for the following situation:

If I have very many tabs, the tab-bar gets a little arrow on the side to scroll through all the open tabs (like in firefox).

[image]

Is there a tomahawk component for creating something similar?

Comment: Needing this may be a sign that you have too many tabs.  Is there no way to refactor your design to avoid this problem?  Your users will probably thank you if you can.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was just a possibility we concidered (and dismissed later).

Answer (score 1):

Are you/have you tried using the [panelTabbedPane](http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/apache-myfaces-tomahawk/tomahawk_pannelTabbedPane_tag.shtml) tag?

Comment: No, I have not tried panelTabbedPane. But I just glanced over it and if I am not mistaken, it misses the feature of scrollable tabs. (Although thanks for the tag - I did not knew it!)